# Can react components be named with numbers?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, create-react-app

I don't remember where, I saw a router using a 404 component like this

```
<Route component={404}/>
```

I have tried creating a component

```
const 404 = props => {
  return (<h1>This is a 404 page!</h1>)
}
```

And it doesn't even compile. I am using create-react-app and React Router.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. JavaScript variables cannot begin with numbers but can contain numbers after the first character.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types

You can name the error component something like `Error404`

Answer (score 5):

React is just JavaScript, and variable names cannot begin with or be only numbers. See the link below

[What characters are valid for JavaScript variable names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/what-characters-are-valid-for-javascript-variable-names)

I would suggest naming it by it's meaning instead, i.e. `<NotFound />`